# TCP dump filter for an ARP H\W address

Tags: pcap, tcpdump

What TCP dump filter should I use to get an ARP packet with a specific H\W address(src or dst) from a pcap dump file ?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I am using [BPF filters](https://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html) as reference, I have used filters for TCP\UDP port, ip addresses etc. but i couldn't find any filters for ARP fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
"arp and ether host xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
```

Refer to the [PCAP-FILTER](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html) man page for more information.